# Shell-script in .app bundle not same environment as invoked in Terminal

Tags: bash, macos

Our application on OS X is invoked by a shell script in `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` which starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and is references in the `Info.plist` as:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
```

Starting the application from the GUI (e.g. double clicking in Finder), this script is launched with different environment variables than when launching the same script from within a Terminal.

What we can do to get the same environment, e.g. environment variables configured in `.profile`?